# pyspark isclose alternatvie

Tags: python, math, pyspark

How can you pass `math.isclose` to pyspark? Pandas can utilize `numpy.isclose` but it will not work with pyspark columns.
I suspect I should use broadcasting but do not know how the code would look like ?

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example *as_text* with the matching expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `isclose`, along with other numpy functions through Pandas UDFs. The [Fugue](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue/) project provides a simplified syntax for doing this.

First we start with a Pandas DataFrame for testing. This will all be Pandas code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a sample DataFrame
data = {
    'A': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    'B': [1.1, 2.2, 3.1],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def check(df: pd.DataFrame, tol) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return df.assign(check=np.isclose(df['A'], df['B'], atol=tol))
    
check(df, 0.1)
```

This will give us:

```
    A   B   check
0   1.0 1.1 True
1   2.0 2.2 False
2   3.0 3.1 True
```

To bring it to Spark, just create the SparkSession and Spark DataFrame.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

Then we can use Fugue, which is a minimal wrapper to bring Python and Pandas code to Spark, Dask, and Ray. If the input is a Spark DataFrame, the output will also be a Spark DataFrame.

```py
from fugue import transform
res = transform(sdf, check, schema="*, check:bool", params={"tol": 0.1})
res.show()
```

And the output will be

```
+---+---+-----+
|  A|  B|check|
+---+---+-----+
|1.0|1.1| true|
|2.0|2.2|false|
|3.0|3.1| true|
+---+---+-----+
```

The schema is a requirement for Spark, Fugue just provides a simplified syntax around it.